# Understanding a foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I've got two `foreach` loops, and I'm using an object generated by WordPress.

In my mind, these should both work the same. However, they don't. Notice `$post` and `$not_a_post` in the loop:

A:

```
$array_A = array( 'posts_per_page' => 2 );
$get_posts_A = get_posts( $array_A );

foreach ( $get_posts_A as $post ) { //uses $post
    the_title(); 
}
```

B:

```
$array_B = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
$get_posts_B = get_posts( $array_B );

foreach ( $get_posts_B as $not_a_post ) {  //uses $not_a_post
    the_title(); 
 }
```

The **only** difference is that I use a variable `$post` for conditional first loop.

I always thought (apparently, incorrectly) the second conditional variable was just a placeholder. So I could do $x, $y, etc.

Can someone explain to me why this foreach loop requires the variable `$post` ?

Comment: Can you explain what the expected result is and what you're getting instead...? This also seems to have little to do with PHP, but instead with Wordpress' idiosyncrasies.

Comment: Please do as @deceze says and post more info, but in the mean-time.  In pure PHP terms, the difference between the two (in terms of what you are asking) is that the first `foreach` loop has the variable `$post` available inside it, the second has `$not_a_post`.  Who knows what `get_posts` does or `the_title()` requires, as you don't show us that code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `the_title()` relies on a variable named exactly `$post` coming from the outer scope, which is a terrible design idea by the way - it should be passed as a parameter to the function, e.g.:

```
the_title($some_id || $some_resource);
```

EDIT: actually WP allows you to pass the post id, [check the code here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php).

Comment: Thanks, so this wouldn't be the case outside of WordPress. Could you elaborate on the parameter to the function?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning wordpress' global variable mess... Could not have said it better

Comment: That's clearer. Is there anything I could change to the current loop in regard to that, or is it a quirk I can't avoid?

Comment: @tmyie you can call `get_the_title($not_a_post)`. Or you can use a cleverly coded software : ))

Comment: @tmyie a rule of thumb: avoid the usage of global variables whenever you can. In general, but especially in wordpress.

Comment: @Thomas That statement can be abbreviated to *Don't use Wordpress.* ;)